# Multiple fragments accessing same database simultaneously

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-contentprovider, android-cursorloader

I happen to have more than one fragments in my activity, all of them are tied to CursorLoaders to fetch data from the Content Providers. All the fragments happen to query the same table but are showing different sets of data from that table. So when my activity will be started, there will be multiple SQL queries running on the same database.

Not sure if the queries will be queued-in internally or simultaneous access will slow down the process, but **is this an efficient way** of handling this scenario? Is there any performance hit or is it better to get all data in a single query?

Note that all queries are for READ access only.

Comment: You're doing it right. No problems at all.

Comment: Yep. No worries here. The implementation of SQLite read-only vs. Read/write access is purely semantic. Under the covers the same implementation is used. That said, be sure to tie up each portion of I/O with a transaction for completeness.

Comment: Thanks OceanLife. Since I am using different CursorLoaders for each of my fragments for making these queries, not sure how to tie up all the queries in a single transaction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no issue if multiple fragments are reading data from same tables.

Happy coding..

Answer (score 1):

sqlite can handle multiple simultaneous reads even from different programs or different threads. sqlite only does exclusive locks when you need to write.